# How to find the centre of GPX data

Tags: center, gpx

Let's say I have some location data from a gpx file.

EG: [36.735058, -3.6843662, 13],[36.73534, -3.6841993, 12],[36.735455, -3.684072, 7],[36.735596, -3.6841817, 6],[36.735943, -3.6840394, 4]

I would like to find the center point using PHP so that when the points are rendered on a map, the map is centered at the center.

I suppose the the center point is some kind of average based on all the points.
Maybe there exists some king of algorithm to calculate  the center.

The way I would approach this is to find the furthest North and South points and then find the point between them and do the same with East and West to find latitude and longitude of the center.

I haven't actually tried doing this this yet.  I am wondering is someone else has already worked out the best way of finding a center point from a group of coordinates.

Comment: More of a math question than a programming question. This may help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256694/how-to-calculate-center-point-in-geographic-coordinates

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works by finding the max  North  South Eat and West points.
Something like this

```
//WORK OUT THE CENTER POINT 

$max_long = max($long_array); 
$min_long = min($long_array); 
$center_long = ($max_long + $min_long) / 2; 

$max_lat = max($lat_array); 
$min_lat = min($lat_array); 
$center_lat = ($max_lat + $min_lat) / 2;
```